# Scrape data from different pages with same url

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this webpage (https://www.fplanalytics.com/history1213.html). I am able to scrape the data from the first page but once I try to go to the next page it keeps giving me back the same data. I have noticed it always retrieves the same URL.

Does anybody have a clues how to get data from the following pages?

```
import requests
import os
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#  create list for html years
years= list(range(1213,2122,101))

# import html into python
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
   "C:/Users/aldi/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.fplanalytics.com/history1213.html')
driver.maximize_window()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'data-table'})

#create empty dataframe and name columns
columns_names = ["player","team","position", "minutes", "goals", "assists", "cs", "tot pts", "bonus"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns_names)

#grab table in one page
#trs = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
#for row in trs:
#    row_data = row.find_all('td')
#    row = [td.text for td in row_data]
#    length = len(df)
#    df.loc[length] = row
    
    
while True: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id':'data-table'})
    trs = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in trs:
        row_data = row.find_all('td')
        row = [td.text for td in row_data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row
    try:
        #grabs the url of the next page
        next_page = soup.find('a', class_ = 'page-link').get('href')
        next_page = 'https://www.fplanalytics.com/history1213.html'+next_page
#        driver.get(next_page)
    except:
        break
    
    #Imports the next pages HTML into python
    page = requests.get(next_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: why are you using the combination of selenium and bs4. If data is dynamic use only selenium!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is being loaded dynamically in page, by Javascript handling the datatable. You can inspect the Network tab in Dev tools, and try to scrape that data endpoint directly. For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
'Origin': 'https://www.fplanalytics.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.fplanalytics.com/',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="103", ".Not/A)Brand";v="99"',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.53 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get('https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fpl.data/db/history201213.json?_=1659263770681', headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
print(df)
```

This returns a dataframe with 422 rows × 17 columns:

```
name    team    position    minutes goals   assists cs  yc  rc  saves   bonus   points  gc  og  ps  pm  _row
0   [Baird] [FUL]   [DEF]   1320    2   0   2   5   0   0   3   45  20  0   0   0   BairdFULDEF
1   [Riise] [FUL]   [DEF]   2529    0   5   8   4   0   0   7   95  41  0   0   0   RiiseFULDEF
2   [Senderos]  [FUL]   [DEF]   1684    0   0   5   6   0   0   1   48  25  0   0   0   SenderosFULDEF
3   [Riether]   [FUL]   [DEF]   3043    1   6   7   4   0   0   11  109 53  0   0   0   RietherFULDEF
4   [Hughes]    [FUL]   [DEF]   2115    0   0   4   1   0   0   3   50  43  0   0   0   HughesFULDEF
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: I tried to run the code from platipus_on_fire. It didn't work for me. I tried to run the code from F.Hoque and it worked totally fine for me. Can someone share some insights into how this solution works? I have seen some similar question on this topic. I have never figured out how the whole headers = {etc} thing works. Is there some tutorials about this? Is there some web site that explains this concept? Thanks!!

Comment: I just ran it again as writen above, and it works.  You mighrt have to update your packages: `pip install -U requests` for example. Did you copy it correctly? What error did you receive?

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. Not sure what happened before. How did you come up with this solution? Is there a web site that explains how this 'mozilla/headers' thing works?

Comment: When you inspect the Network tab, and click on the XHR request, it will show you more details, like `Request Headers` - you just recreate that. Headers are nothing but how the browser/robot visiting a url present itself to the server. Based on the header, server can choose to accept, or deny browser's request.

Comment: Oh, I see it! Very cool! Thanks for sharing this insight!!